# got error regarding sdk version in android

Tags: java, android, performance

I got a error which says:

> Call requires API level 3 (current min is 1): android.os.AsyncTask#

This is the code I used for retrieving data from database through PHP into `listview`. For that I ran the thread.

Here is the code:

```
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
private final FetchDataListener listener;
private String msg;

public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener) {// this is a exact error place
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if(params == null) return null;

    //do something
}
```

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: change android:minSdkVersion to 3 in android manifest file

Answer (score 4):

Right Click on Project And select properties and then select android and then change **project build target**

and also open **AndroidManifest.xml** and set :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

instead of **integer Value 1** change to 9 like above

Comment: In most cases, there is no reason to support below version 9 (Gingerbread) of the SDK. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html for a list of what API Levels correspond to which Android versions.

Comment: I have done these thing. but nothing changed. error is still there

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:minSdkVersion="1"` to `android:minSdkVersion="3"` in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.